# Стоит ли оставить принятый ответ закрепленным выше других ответов по умолчанию?

Tags: обсуждение, сортировка-ответов

Некоторое время назад [была изменена сортировка ответов на Stack Overflow на английском](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411352/): теперь ответ с наибольшим рейтингом отображается выше остальных, даже если он не был отмечен принятым. Это идея не новая, первый раз ее [начали обсуждать еще 2013 году](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top).

[Сегодня у нас есть возможность выбрать](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/274323), хотим ли мы видеть на Stack Overflow на русском ответы с наибольшем рейтингом выше остальных.

Давайте примем решение вместе. Пожалуйста, поделитесь вашими мыслями.

---

**Обновление**

По результатам обсуждения я открепил принятый ответ в настройках сайта.

Comment: а где будет находиться ответ с галочкой?

Comment: @Grundy Он будет отсортирован согласно его рейтингу.

Comment: @Grundy отсортирован буден согласно выбранному типу сортировки (голоса/возраст/активность). Т.е. наличие галочки просто перестаёт влиять вовсе на сортировку. Можно самостоятельно на enSO проверить поведение.

Comment: тогда смысл галочки теряется вообще :)

Comment: @Grundy смысл галочки остаётся прежним - это "ответ, который лучше всего подошёл автору вопроса".

Comment: Не понял как голосовать за или против) Ответ давать не вижу смысла в этом топике, а вот какую-то голосовалку устроить было бы неплохо.  В целом я за то, чтобы открепить галочку от верха

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Думаю, все–таки через ответы это лучше делать. Ответ за ниже есть. Можно за него голосовать или свои аргументы за написать :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, невозможно же стало нормально enSO пользоваться на популярных вопросах :(

Comment: А можно при сортировке просто учитывать галочку как дополнительный +1 голос?

Comment: @avp На данный момент так сделать нельзя. Предложения такие на MSE есть, да.

Comment: Есть ли возможность добавить переключатель (открепления принятого ответа) к кнопкам метода сортировки ответов? Если да, то каждый участник сможет сам выбирать удобный ему вариант - это выглядит как наиболее эффективное решение. Конечно, в техническом плане это потребует переноса кода сортировки в клиентскую часть, но такое изменение будет только плюсом (сейчас вообще неясно, почему сортировкой до сих пор сервер занимается, то есть зачем рефрешить всю страницу вопроса только лишь для изменения порядка следования ее элементов).

Comment: _«Если да, то каждый участник сможет сам выбирать удобный ему вариант»_ - точнее, поменять вариант принятый по-умолчанию (выбирать дефолтный все же придется, но так само изменение будет менее "ломающим" в случае если решение будет за открепление).

Comment: @yar85, кому кроме нескольких десятков *исследователей-энтузиастов* это может понадобиться?

Comment: @avp, если "это" - сортировка ответов или открепление принятого, то оно видимо уже понадобилось кому-то кроме обозначенных десятков... раз на enSO такое изменение уже принято.

Comment: Количество плюсов у ответа - это вещь в достаточной степени объективная (если, конечно, их не полторы штуки). А вот полезность ответа именно для автора (что отмечается галкой "принят"), тем более полезность для третьего участника, нашедшего тему поиском - в высшей степени субъективная, на которую ориентироваться особого смысла нет. Сортировка по рейтингу ответа вне зависимости от флага принятости - имеет смысл, но при условии, что он не ниже вменяемого порога качественности ответа (например, не менее 5 плюсов).

Comment: "По результатам обсуждения я открепил принятый ответ в настройках сайта." Но это вовсе не значит, что не нужно больше ставить галочку.

Answer (score 22):

Учитывая, что SO как бы "база знаний", а не просто помощь в получении ответа одному вопрошающему, кажется логичным не принимать во внимание галочку на ответе при сортировке. Чтобы люди, пришедшие из поисковиков (хотя бы даже внутренних поисковых запросов), получали в первую очередь наиболее полезный ответ, а не тот, который приглянулся задавшему вопрос.

Усугублять ситуацию могут и старые, но популярные вопросы, авторы которых уже забросили сайт или вовсе удалили аккаунт. Т.к. со временем правильность ответа с галочкой может устареть, а наиболее актуальный, по идее, должен продолжать получать голоса и всплывать наверх (при сортировке по голосам).

При этом для автора вопроса хорошо было бы оставить закрепление галочкой в силе, чтобы он в первую очередь видел принятый им же ответ. Тем более, что он всегда имеет возможность галочку переставить.

Comment: Последний параграф: очень крутое преложение! Пожалуйста, опубликуйте его на MSE!

Comment: Вот со вторым абзацем не вполне согласен. Потому что часто вижу что именно галочка - и есть самый популярный ответ для своего времени. А вот новые голоса на более актуальные ответы с современным подходом капают как кран в засуху. Но с этим вряд ли что-то можно сделать.

Comment: Логично, и в какой-то степени верно. Но есть одно но. Нередко замечал, что более развернутые и (очевидно) наиболее полезные ответы по отношению к остальным ответам имеют меньшее количество голосов. В таком случае, самые полезные ответы будут сортироваться ниже остальных, чем того заслуживают, и тем самым рушится логика `Чтобы люди ... получали в первую очередь наиболее полезный ответ`. На мой взгляд пользователь самостоятельно для себя должен принимать решение, какой ответ для него является наиболее полезным. Любая сортировка - это только сортировка, и только.

Comment: @Sevastopol' зависит о того, как оценивать полезность. Развёрнутый ответ с растеканием мысли на несколько экранов вполне можно посчитать менее полезным, чем другой более лаконичный ответ, лучше подготовленный для выполнения Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V и решения проблемы того, кто пришёл к нему из поисковика.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, кажется, я достаточно четко сформулировал мысль `... (очевидно) наиболее полезные ответы ... В таком случае, самые полезные ответы будут ...`. Или нет?

Comment: @Sevastopol' речь о формулировке "полезности", а не мысли.

Answer (score 10):

А почему бы не предоставить юзеру уникальную возможность это кастомизировать так как он пожелает? У нас 21 век на дворе, дроны бороздят Большой театр, а мы всем колхозом решаем, вопрос, который можно закрыть одной галкой в настройках "Пинить ответ сверху".

Comment: Я только за, но что-то галочки в настройках не популярны у разработчиков SO...

Comment: Вероятно, под этим лежат какие-то исследования, вроде того, что (я рассуждаю) галканутый ответ, даже имеющий низкое качество, будучи висящим сверху, будет получать лайки именно потому что он галканутый (и висит сверху).

Comment: Для Qwertiy такая галочка определённо нужна, а для незарегистрированных и свежезарегистрировавшихся всё равно нужно выбрать какое-то значение по умолчанию

Comment: @Qwertiy если не в настройках, то прям на странице с ответами, там где сейчас уже есть три фильтра "текущие"/"по дате публикации"/"голоса"

Comment: @andreymal, у незарегистрированного по умолчанию сортировка по голосам, да и удалённые посты он не видит.

Comment: В любом случае какой-то результат должен быть по умолчанию, даже если добавить галочку в настройки.

Answer (score 6):

Считаю что стоит оставить закрепленным если он отмечен значит помог скорее всего. И из Гугла пришедший человек скорее всего найдёт ответ в нём и не придется листать как на форуме. по моему даже новым покажется глупым найти отмеченной ответ на 101 месте. Даже если он не лучший но обычно он полезен и много места не занимает в сравнении со всеми оставшимися. Он был отмечен не просто так скорее всего. Если не ставить на первое место то лучше вовсе убрать функцию отмеченного ответа. Можно добавить функцию лучший ответ кроме отмеченного как вариант, который принимается админами иле модемами, это лучше чем ставить на первое место популярный ответ, если я нашёл в ответе полезности для меня я лайкаю так сказать, и не важно ответ ли ето на заданный вопрос автором.

Answer (score 5):

Для новичков, гостей из гугла вероятно решение открепить принятый ответ - самое правильное. Но оно никак или почти никак не решает проблему устаревших ответов. Ответ 10-летней давности будет иметь рейтинг выше, чем самый правильный, крутой и современный ответ, данный месяц назад.

На самом деле вопрос больше актуален для для английского SO, так как там больше старых вопросов с ответами по 1000+ рейтинга, которые опубликованы на втором месте после принятого ответа с рейтингом 300.

По факту, здесь у нас открепление либо ни на что не повлияет, либо повлияет на очень небольшое число ответов, потому что как правило принятый ответ имеет больший рейтинг, чем все остальные, а чаще всего он вообще один.

То есть, я считаю, что проблема открепления для русского SO - не проблема, либо я ее не заметил. И изменение правил открепления особо погоды не сделает.

Единственное, что я вижу лично для себя, так это потеря логики в отображении ответов. Когда в топе непринятый ответ, то кажется, что принятого ответа вовсе нет, UI никак не помогает это определить. Когда принятый ответ вверху, этой проблемы нет, всё весьма однозначно.

**Я за то, чтобы правило сортировки ответов с поднятием в топ принятых** если и не было по умолчанию для всех, то **оставалось доступным всем желающим**. И лично для себя я это прикрепление оставлю, мне так удобнее. И как отвечающему, и как гуглящему. Если опции такой не будет, подожду недельку и пойду искать расширение для браузера на английской Мете, умельцы быстро найдут способ прикрепить принятые ответы обратно. Так что не смертельно.

От себя просьба участникам активнее и ответственнее голосовать.

Comment: [Для закрепления уже написали код](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369579/339911).

Answer (score 4):

Однозначно стоит оставлять закреплённым.

Подход без закрепления ответа совершенно неудобен.

Лично я всегда использую сортировку по последнему изменению. В совокупности с закреплённым принятым ответом она почти всегда позволяет эффективно сделать то, зачем пришёл:

1. Если я просто лазию по сайту в поисках чего-то интересного либо смотрю обновления, такая сортировка отлично подходит.
2. Если я пришёл в какой-то сложный вопрос, где мне надо понять происходящее, то всё равно буду просматривать все ответы и сортировка почти не играет роли.
3. Если я пришёл чтобы просто вспомнить что-то, что я знаю, но забыл конкретный метод, или что-то в этом духе, то почти всегда нужная информация содержится в принятом ответе, который стоит на первом месте независимо от сортировки.

Таким образом я могу спокойно пользоваться сайтом не переключая сортировку.

---

А вот сейчас на enSO закрепление ответа отключили. И если я в третьем случае прихожу в популярный вопрос, то там наверху болтаются даже не просто свежие ответы (которые не приносят новой информации), там болтается удалённый мусор по типу "а как вот это сделать", "а у меня не получилось" и подобное. В каком-то вопросе я проматывал с десяток удалённых мусорных ответов (к сожалению, не сделал скриншот) ради того, чтобы найти оно интересующее меня слово - название функции.

Но есть вот такой пример: [как в питоне отделить номер группы от цифр](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5984633/4928642). Принятый ответ с конструкцией `r'\g<1>123'` находится в конце третьего экрана (впрочем, это увидят только те, у кого репутация достигла 10К):

> [image: скриншот примера]

Comment: Минусаторы, ну хоть говорите, с чем не согласны.

Comment: То ли ты не понял вопроса, то ли я не понял твоего ответа)) В приведённом тобой скрине вверху болтаются активные ответы. Если по дефолту сортировка будет по количеству голосов (как предлагается), то они как раз провалятся вниз

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я в курсе об этом же есть в моём ответе. Но в текущем варианте принятый ответ первый несмотря на сортировку, именно поэтому у меня всегда выставлена одна и та же сортировка, при которой пользоваться сайтом вполне комфортно... Было, до того, как отключили запиненность. И что значит "как предполагается"? Сортировку выставляет сам пользователь и она применяется ко всему сайту.

Comment: Ну я пока не видел там ничего сверхкритичного. Возможно потому что https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11766/#comment50586_11767

Comment: _«Минусаторы, ну хоть говорите, с чем не согласны»_ - с первыми двумя предложениями, т.е. с самой сутью ответа (если правильно понял что суть в этом). Личный опыт далее - не вызвал интереса/отклика. Замечание о том что удаленный мусор мешается - справедливо, но это скорее естественное следствие сортировки по активности, чем недостаток конкретно открепления принятого ответа... Другой метод сортировки, по голосам, разве не подходит ко всем трем указанным кейсам (и по смыслу, и по результату)? А нежелание переключать сортировку, уже индивидуально (и оно не должно влиять на общее решение, имхо).

Comment: @yar85, для основного использования сайта - просматривать и отвечать, а не искать ответ на вопрос, сортировка по голосам совершенно неудобна.

Comment: `где мне надо понять происходящее, то всё равно буду просматривать все ответы и сортировка почти не играет роли.` - ключевое. И должно быть самым верным действием для любого пользователя, если конечно у него имеется царь в голове.

Comment: Плюсую за это - `Однозначно стоит оставлять закреплённым.`. На (первый) мой взгляд (возможно и ошибочный) приоритет должен быть. Но если подойти к обдумыванию сортировки более глубоко, а не так с кондачка, то нужно время.

Answer (score 1):

Мне как новому пользователю удобнее просматривать по рейтингу. Ведь чем больше плюсиков , тем большему количеству людей это пригодилось. По личному опыту, выбираю ответ, который мне понятен, а не тот который эффективен. Порой это расходится с самым популярным ответом. Это говорит о низком уровне знаний, но мы говорим про юзабилити. Поэтому, так будет поступить правильнее. На мой взгляд.